# Allow specific datetime formats in asp.net core app on json deserialization

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, json-deserialization

I want to allow specific datetime formats in my asp.net core app.

I have this code in Startup.cs on ConfigureServices method:

```
...

services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   ...
   options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
})

...
```

This property allow only one datetime format.

I'm needing something like this (with many datetime formats permitted):

```
...

services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   ...
   options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = { "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy", ... };
});

...
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to do it in C# Code and then just send it as JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Logically, how would the serializer know which format to actually apply? There's no `Date` type, so a `DateTime`, even if it no time component is set is still a `DateTime` and will simply return the time as midnight (`00:00:00`).

You're struggling here with a basic flaw in API design. An API should not return different types for the same member(s). If time is a component ever, then time should always be present, even if it's zeroed out. Returning different responses puts additional and sometimes impossible burdens on the client.

Comment: In some ASP.NET Projects (no .net core) i'm used this type of custom converter class: [link](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-custom-datetime-converter-json-net-non-standard-empty-string-null-value-date-format)

Comment: I'm needing something like that for deserialize a json.

Comment: You can control that by defining custom value resolvers on your DTO class(es). Each DTO will only be able to response to one particular format, but you can use different DTOs in different scenarios.

Comment: I don't believe it's "not possible". It's possible within some constraints. I used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support to make up for the fact that my input data was coming in the relaxed ISO 8601 format (no "T" between date and time), but that code will work for any unambiguous date format. It's still going to have problems with dates like '1/2/2000'

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support:

```
public class DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}

class Program
{

    private static void ProcessDateTimeWithCustomConverter()
    {
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        options.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse());

        string testDateTimeStr = "04-10-2008 6:30 AM";
        string testDateTimeJson = @"""" + testDateTimeStr + @"""";

        DateTime resultDateTime = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DateTime>(testDateTimeJson, options);
        Console.WriteLine(resultDateTime);

        string resultDateTimeJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(DateTime.Parse(testDateTimeStr), options);
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(resultDateTimeJson));
    }
}
```

This *should* handle any unambiguous date/time.